How to toggle ::after properties with JS
I am making a website and there is a subscription page where there are four buttons. I have a circle on the top right of the container containing the button. the circle is made of a ::before element that is always shown there is also a ::after element that I want to toggle when the button is clicked so that it marks for which subscription is the information shown but I can't think of a way for the ::after element display to be toggled to block with JS.


function openCity(evt, cityName){
  var i, tabcontent;

  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
}
.tab{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.tablinks{
  all: unset;
  background: #111111;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 10rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container{
  position: relative
}

.circle{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.circle::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2.5px;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #e8f1f2;
}

.circle::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 50%;
  right: 7.5px;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.tabcontent{
  display: none;
}
<div class="tab">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '1')">1</button>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '3')">3</button>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '6')">6</button>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '12')">12</button>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="showplace">
    <div id="1" class="tabcontent">1</div>
    <div id="3" class="tabcontent">3</div>
    <div id="6" class="tabcontent">6</div>
    <div id="12" class="tabcontent">12</div>
  </div>




from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333
